# Access different Streams in Skype for Business conference session

Tags: skype-for-business, skypedeveloper

Which API would be used to access the various streams in a Skype for Business conference?  For example, is it possible to record the audio stream only, or the shared desktop independently?  Would this need to be done at the server or client level?

Suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

At the moment the recordings you are ask for are only [client based](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Record-and-play-back-a-Skype-for-Business-meeting-6d1dd3c5-ded7-4935-8db0-d6d7173c482f). The Skype for Business environment do not have an option to perform such recordings on an native way. However there are 3rd party components which can do a server based recording (see [here](https://www.skypefeedback.com/forums/299913-generally-available/suggestions/8493577-server-side-recording), [here](http://www.verba.com/skype-for-business-recording-and-compliance), [here](https://www.actiance.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/Actiance_Datasheet_Vantage_for_Skype_for_Business.pdf) and [here](http://www.lyncinsider.com/third-party-lync-products/record-calls-lync-skype-recording-go-2015/)). So for the moment you need to use the client side way to access he streams you need if you do not with so involve a 3rd party software.